# Different width for table rows

Tags: html, css

I try to split the middle row and keep the upper row and bottom as-is.

```html
<table border="1" width="500">
    <tbody>
        <tr bgcolor="red">
            <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="80%">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="green">
            <td width="50%" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="50%">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="blue">
            <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How do I split the middle row into two equal columns, using one table tag?

Comment: Don't use `border` attribute. Don't use `width` attribute. Don't use `bgcolor` attribute. Don't use `&nbsp;` when you want something different than preventing a break between words.

Comment: Thx for the comment, I did it just to simplify the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add more colspan:

```css
table {
  width: 500px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border: 1px outset;
}
tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 80%;
}
td::after {
  content: '\200B'; /* Insert zero-width space */
}
table { border: 1px outset; }
td    { border: 1px inset;  }
tr:nth-child(1) { background: red;   }
tr:nth-child(2) { background: green; }
tr:nth-child(3) { background: blue;  }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1" width="500">
    <tbody>
  <tr bgcolor="red">
    <td  idth="10%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="80%" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="10%">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="green">
    <td width="50%" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="50%" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="blue">
    <td  width="100%" colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The request was to keep the upper row and bottom as-is!

Comment: my bad. fixed now. Cheers